# cvxpy.error.SolverError: The solver CBC is not installed in windows 10 python?

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy, cvxopt

I have tried to install cvxpy and cvxopt both packages by using pip command the package was installed successfully but while running my code i'm getting error like CBC not installed inside "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py". I tried with many solution but not working could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Last time i checked cbc will need customized install-steps which are annoying on windows. I recommend sticking to glpk, where cvxopt brings binaries.

Comment: but using glpk is slower optimization and CBC is fast correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough enough reputation to add comments, so I will post this as an answer.

CBC requires cylp to be installed.
try

```
    import cylp
```

if it throws error, install it using

```
    pip install cylp
```

go through this link for more details 
https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/687